# Idiom meaning :he didn't pull his punches

Tags: idioms

I want to know the meaning of this "he didn't pull his punches last night when he spoken"

Answer (score 2):

Means he didn't hold back. In the case of your sentence he said exactly what was on his mind, potentially at the risk of offending someone, or having his own reputation damaged.

pull (one's) punches

> 1. To act as if one is punching someone, without making any or much physical contact. (Short for "pull one's punches.") 
>    "I know
>      you're trying to make the scene realistic, but please pull your
>      punches next time!"
> 2. By extension, to restrain one's commentary or criticism to avoid offending or upsetting someone. (Usually used in the negative.) 
>    "I want
>      your honest opinion of my story—don't pull your punches! Wow, your
>      aunt really doesn't pull her punches. Is my sweatshirt really that
>      ugly?"
>     [dictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+punches)

It's an idiom, because to pull one's punches isn't as clear as "hold short one's punches" in sparring training or acting out a scene.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding it means to speak in an honest way without trying to be kind.

A very straight forward person or being blunt or giving a frank opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If i may, use one idiom to explain another:

**no holds barred**   [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/barred)

> having no restraints or restrictions

As in:

Mr/Ms spoke last evening on sensitive topic X with no holds barred!